# How can i display the file name in the Edit View? File name is stored in the images Folder and also in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

View is

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ChooseFile, "", new { @class = "span12", placeholder = "Choose File",type="file"})`

when i Edit it then i need the file name picked and stored in the database. also image is stored in the folder image.

I also need to give download option for the same.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you attempt any code for this use case?

Comment: HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }

Comment: Above code is used for the adding file and it does but in Edit i need to get the file name with choose option stored for that.

Comment: Update regarding the question must be added editing your post and not on comments.

Comment: Refer to the code sample and read the link for more details

Comment: Cant see the your beginForm() but remember you need to add **enctype** for file uploads . `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options

1. If file size is small, read the bytes from db and send as file result from MBC controller
2. If file is large, then try streaming.

You can try like this

```
  public FileContentResult GetFile(int id)
  {
     SqlDataReader rdr; byte[] fileContent = null; 
     string mimeType = "";string fileName = "";
     const string connect = @"Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=FileTest;Trusted_Connection=True;";

     using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
     {
        var qry = "SELECT FileContent, MimeType, FileName FROM FileStore WHERE ID = @ID";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
        conn.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
          {
             rdr.Read();
             fileContent = (byte[])rdr["FileContent"];
             mimeType = rdr["MimeType"].ToString();
             fileName = rdr["FileName"].ToString();
          }
        }
        return File(fileContent, mimeType, fileName);
      }
```

Comment: Try with the sample code here:  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/125/asp-net-mvc-uploading-and-downloading-files

Comment: @saravanan yeah i was wondering about that ... 3K + and formatting like a n0ob ;)

Comment: Yes, having a hard time formatting from my android mobile browser. Editors don't have options as full blown browsers do...